# Spring MVC Hibernate Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource could not be loaded error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to integrate hibernate with Spring. Until I dont introduce hibernate code & the libraries, it works fine. Here is the code,

welcome-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="EmployeeService" class="java4s.service.EmployeeServiceImpl" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:IMS"
    p:username="username"
    p:password="password" />
</beans>
```

Controller.java

```
public boolean validateLogin(String username, String password) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        query.setString(1, username);
        query.setString(2, password);
        return query.list().size() > 0;

    }
```

Libraries

```
antlr-2.7.7
aopalliance-1.0
classmate-1.0.0
commons-logging-1.2
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final
hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final
jandex-1.1.0.Final
javassist-3.18.1-GA
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final
jstl-1.2
ojdbc6
spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE
validation-api-1.1.0.Final
xml-apis-1.0.b2
```

Error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource could not be loaded
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource could not be loaded
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:205)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    java4s.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.validateLogin(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:58)
    java4s.controller.LoginSuccessController.loginvalidateForm(LoginSuccessController.java:61)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:202)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    java4s.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.validateLogin(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:58)
    java4s.controller.LoginSuccessController.loginvalidateForm(LoginSuccessController.java:61)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

It seems the problem I am getting is from this line.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

How can I solve the problem?

**EDIT**

Error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource could not be loaded

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource could not be loaded

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource could not be loaded
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource could not be loaded
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:205)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    java4s.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.validateLogin(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:58)
    java4s.controller.LoginSuccessController.loginvalidateForm(LoginSuccessController.java:61)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:202)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    java4s.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.validateLogin(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:58)
    java4s.controller.LoginSuccessController.loginvalidateForm(LoginSuccessController.java:61)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.41 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driverClassName shouldn't be a Datasource:

```
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
```

It should be the class name of the Driver class: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

```
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
```

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Look at the end of the stacktrace or add it as update to your question

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava have you changed the code and redeployed you application? I doesn't looks so

Comment: sorry, it was using `hibernate.cfg.xml` for Database connection. I used your suggestion in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, it worked there.